# Drop duplicates based on first level column in MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a MultiIndex Pandas DataFrame like so:

```
+---+------------------+----------+---------+--------+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+
|   | VECTOR           | SEGMENTS | OVERALL                      | INDIVIDUAL                       |
|   |                  |          | TIP X   | TIP Y  | CURVATURE | TIP X      | TIP Y   | CURVATURE |
| 0 | (TOP, TOP)       | 2        | 3.24    | 1.309  | 44        | 1.62       | 0.6545  | 22        |
| 1 | (TOP, BOTTOM)    | 2        | 3.495   | 0.679  | 22        | 1.7475     | 0.3395  | 11        |
| 2 | (BOTTOM, TOP)    | 2        | 3.495   | -0.679 | -22       | 1.7475     | -0.3395 | -11       |
| 3 | (BOTTOM, BOTTOM) | 2        | 3.24    | -1.309 | -44       | 1.62       | -0.6545 | -22       |
+---+------------------+----------+---------+--------+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+
```

How can I drop duplicates based on all columns contained under `'OVERALL'` or `'INDIVIDUAL'`? So if I choose `'INDIVIDUAL'` to drop duplicates from the values of `TIP X`, `TIP Y`, and `CURVATURE` under `INDIVIDUAL` must all match for it to be a duplicate?

And further, as you can see from the table `1` and `2` are duplicates that are simply mirrored about the x-axis. These must also be dropped.

Also, can I center the `OVERALL` and `INDIVIDUAL` headings?

EDIT: `frame.drop_duplicates(subset=['INDIVIDUAL'], inplace=True)` produces `KeyError: Index(['INDIVIDUAL'], dtype='object')`

Comment: Possible duplicate. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377767/drop-duplicates-from-level-in-hierarchical-index-pandas

Comment: Saw that during my search but that seems to remove duplicates from the headings not the dataframe itself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass pandas `.drop_duplicates` a subset of tuples for multi-indexed columns:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=[
    ('INDIVIDUAL', 'TIP X'),
    ('INDIVIDUAL', 'TIP Y'),
    ('INDIVIDUAL', 'CURVATURE')
])
```

Or, if your row indices are unique, you could use the following approach that saves some typing:

```
df.loc[df['INDIVIDUAL'].drop_duplicates().index]
```

*Update*:

As you suggested in the comments, if you want to do operations on the dataframe you can do that in-line:

```
df.loc[df['INDIVIDUAL'].abs().drop_duplicates().index]
```

Or for non-pandas functions, you can use `.transform`:

```
df.loc[df['INDIVIDUAL'].transform(np.abs).drop_duplicates().index]
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['INDIVIDUAL'].drop_duplicates().index]` is not working on the mirrored values. Any way to specify `abs()` in this method?

Comment: For absolute values I would just use a helper dataframe, so `df2 = df['INDIVIDUAL']; df2['col1'] = np.abs(df2['col1']); df.loc[df2.drop_duplicates().index]`

Comment: Apologies, immediately after asking the question I googled and found that I can simply add Pandas' own `.abs()` into the mix. This worked for me `frame = frame.loc[frame['INDIVIDUAL'].abs().drop_duplicates().index]`